# Tensorflow : IOU per class

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use deeplab for semantic segmentation. I'd like to calculate IOU per class(IOU for person only) instead of mean IOU.

At L142 of
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/eval.py,
I tried to get confusion matrix instead of mean IOU by

```
miou, cmat = tf.metrics.mean_iou(...)
metric_map['cmat'] = cmat
```

but it did not work.
I'd appreciate if someone suggest me how to get around.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_streaming_confusion_matrix` from `tensorflow.python.ops.metrics_impl` to get the confusion matrix.
Essentially it works the same way as other running metrics like `mean_iou`. which means, you get two ops when calling this metric, a total confusion_matrix op and an update op that updates the confusion matrix cumulatively.

With the confusion matrix, now you should be able to compute the class wise iou

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a class-specific IoU metric for this very purpose based on the MeanIoU class.

```
class ClassIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
"""Computes the class-specific Intersection-Over-Union metric.

IOU is defined as follows:
  IOU = true_positive / (true_positive + false_positive + false_negative).
The predictions are accumulated in a confusion matrix, weighted by
`sample_weight` and the metric is then calculated from it.

If `sample_weight` is `None`, weights default to 1.
Use `sample_weight` of 0 to mask values.

Args:
  class_idx: The index of the the class of interest
  one_hot: Indicates if the input is a one_hot vector as in CategoricalCrossentropy or if the class indices
    are used as in SparseCategoricalCrossentropy or MeanIoU
  num_classes: The possible number of labels the prediction task can have.
    This value must be provided, since a confusion matrix of dimension =
    [num_classes, num_classes] will be allocated.
  name: (Optional) string name of the metric instance.
  dtype: (Optional) data type of the metric result.
"""
def __init__(self, class_idx, one_hot, num_classes, name=None, dtype=None):
    super().__init__(num_classes, name, dtype)
    self.one_hot = one_hot
    self.class_idx = class_idx

def result(self):
    sum_over_row = tf.cast(
        tf.reduce_sum(self.total_cm, axis=0), dtype=self._dtype)
    sum_over_col = tf.cast(
        tf.reduce_sum(self.total_cm, axis=1), dtype=self._dtype)
    true_positives = tf.cast(
        tf.linalg.diag_part(self.total_cm), dtype=self._dtype)

    # sum_over_row + sum_over_col =
    #     2 * true_positives + false_positives + false_negatives.
    denominator = sum_over_row[self.class_idx] + sum_over_col[self.class_idx] \
        - true_positives[self.class_idx]

    # The mean is only computed over classes that appear in the
    # label or prediction tensor. If the denominator is 0, we need to
    # ignore the class.
    num_valid_entries = tf.reduce_sum(
        tf.cast(tf.not_equal(denominator, 0), dtype=self._dtype))

    iou = tf.math.divide_no_nan(true_positives[self.class_idx], denominator)

    return tf.math.divide_no_nan(
        tf.reduce_sum(iou, name='mean_iou'), num_valid_entries)

def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    if self.one_hot:
        return super().update_state(tf.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), sample_weight)
    else:
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
```